# How to scan multiple directory locations for files with only one input-channel-adapter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, file-handling, poller

I have a assignment where I am reading two different folders for the files using spring-integration inbound-channel-adapter.

My bean is defined as below:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="channel1"
    directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/input1">
    <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="60000">
    </integration:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="channel2"
    directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/input2">
    <integration:poller id="poller2" fixed-delay="60000">
    </integration:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="channel1" ref="handler" />
<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="channel2" ref="handler" />

<bean id="handler" class="c.d.Handler" />
```

I want to read the files from both the location and to whichever location it comes I want to process it with same handler class. I cannot write two main classes to read different inbound-channel-adapters. I have tried adding scanner to the same but it didn't workout. I had tried above but it is giving error **expected single matching bean but found 2:**. Any help upon this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare one service activator with `input-channel="in"`, then your two adapters...

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="one" channel="channel" ...

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="two" channel="channel" ...
```

i.e. route the output from both adapters to the same bean.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing the same what you said but I am getting a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException with the reason that it is looking for single FileReadingMessageSource but found 2.

Comment: RIght there are two beans; it sounds like you are trying to autowire one of them; you will need a `@Qualifier`; you need to show the rest of your config and exactly what you are trying to do.